# Concurrency in golang

Tags: go, concurrency

I have a question about concurrency in GoLang. Here is a sample code in GoLang

```
package main

import(
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

var m int
func add(i int){
    m++
}

func main() {
    m = 0
    for i:=0;i<100;i++{
        go add(i)
    }
    time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 1000)
    fmt.Println(m)
}
```

When I execute it I always have the same result 100, even if I execute it several times.

If I do the same code in C (without mutex), sometimes I have different results.

And my question, I would like to know if GoLang implicitly manages access to a shared variable using an internal mechanism ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. For example, using your program,

```
$ go run -race dz00dz.go
==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Read at 0x000000595200 by goroutine 7:
  main.add()
     /home/peter/gopath/src/dz00dz.go:11 +0x3d

Previous write at 0x000000595200 by goroutine 6:
  main.add()
      /home/peter/gopath/src/dz00dz.go:11 +0x59

Goroutine 7 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      /home/peter/gopath/src/dz00dz.go:17 +0x76

Goroutine 6 (finished) created at:
  main.main()
      /home/peter/gopath/src/dz00dz.go:17 +0x76
==================
100
Found 1 data race(s)
exit status 66
```

References:

[Introducing the Go Race Detector](https://blog.golang.org/race-detector)

Answer (score 3):

I am getting the same results here, but not if I replace

```
m++
```

with

```
func add(i int) {
    for j := 0; j < 100000; j++ {
        m++
    }
}
```

In the latter case, I confirmed using [scheduler tracing](https://www.goinggo.net/2015/02/scheduler-tracing-in-go.html) that the Go runtime distributed the work on several processor cores, which explains the discrepancy because, indeed, `m` is not protected against race conditions. So why does it not happen in the former case ? Probably because a simple integer increment is too short for the Go scheduler to assign the goroutines to several threads, so they execute in sequence, in the same thread. And why does it happen in C : because you manually distribute the calculations on several threads, so the operating system scheduler may decide to execute them on several processor cores.

Answer (score 1):

You have a race condition here, try to test your code with:

```
go test -race
```

It means that `m++` is not thread-safe, try something like this:

```
var (
    m int
    mu *sync.RWMutex
)

func add(i int){
    mu.Lock()
    m++
    mu.Unlock()
}
```

Also I see this code is a bit dirty:
1. Remove `m = 0`
2. Replace `Sleep` with `WaitGroup`
3. Why do you pass `i` but do not use it?

Comment: I have used i before I post this code, and when I post this code I forget to remove it

Answer (score 0):

No, you cant get the same result.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

var m int

func add(i int) {
    m++
}

func main() {
    m = 0
    for i := 0; i < 10000; i++ {
        go add(i)
    }
    time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 1000)
    fmt.Println(m)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Goroutines do not run in parallel. Go work scheduler manages all the goroutines such that all the goroutines are run effectively. Since, goroutines are not running in parallel, the answer would always be 100 for the above program. But, there is one setting GOMAXPROCS which is by default 1, but if you set it any number N > 1, the answer would be different everytime since N goroutines are running in parallel.